# Вопрос по размещению Google Tag Manager

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager

Необходимо добавить код в *Google Tag Manager* `<head>` и `<body>` сайта. 
Сайт на `WordPress`. Многостраничный.

Мне нужно добавить код на главную страницу и еще одну, для настройки гугл аналитики.

Но я не совсем понимаю как эти эти страницы могут называться в файл-менеджере  и в какой файл мне добавлять этот код? 
Как он называется? 
Подскажите примерный путь к нему.

PS. Необходимо добавить код *Google Tag Manager* в сайт.

Comment: Поправлю. Необходимо добавить код Google Tag Manager в сайт.

Comment: В Вашем случае наверное лучше воспользоваться одним из [плагинов](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/search/Google+Tag+Manager/) для этого. Если по каким-то причинам плагин не подходит, то обычно это файл `header.php`. В случае если тема из официального каталога или маркетплейса по типу Themeforest, то эти правки нужно делать в дочерней теме, так как изменения будут утеряны после обновления файлов темы до актуальной версии в дальнейшем.

Comment: <body <?php body_class(); ?>> Скажите пожалуйста, куда мне тут вставлять код для body. Написано сразу после открывающего тега. Это сразу после <body?

Comment: Я исправила комментарий

Comment: Нет, после сразу после `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`. На следующей строке.

Comment: Большое спасибо!